# Integer constants

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I declare a string constant like so:

You should create a header file like

```
// Constants.h
extern NSString * const MyFirstConstant;
extern NSString * const MySecondConstant;
//etc.
```

You can include this file in each file that uses the constants or in the pre-compiled header for the project.

You define these constants in a .m file like

```
// Constants.m

NSString * const MyFirstConstant = @"FirstConstant";
NSString * const MySecondConstant = @"SecondConstant";
```

What do I do to define integer constants?

Answer (score 39):

Replace NSString* with NSInteger.

This is true of any constant type, be it a primitive such as int/float, or a class such as NSString or NSInteger.

The only thing to be aware of is whether you desire a constant or a pointer to a constant (such as withNSString), and how it's initialized in the .m file

**Integer example:**

```
// constants.h
extern NSInteger const MyIntegerConstant;

// constants.m
NSInteger const MyIntegerConstant = 666;
```

(Note: for the reason why NSInteger instead of just regular "int", see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725/in-cocoa-do-you-prefer-nsinteger-or-just-regular-int-and-why))

**Class example:**

```
// constants.h
extern MyClass* const MyClassConstant;

// constants.m
MyClass* const MyClassConstant= [[MyClass alloc] initWith: paramOne and:paramTwo];
```

Comment: Thanks andrew - Were would this class be deallocated?

Comment: It wouldn't be, it's memory would be cleaned up when the program exits. If you wish to have manual control over this you can add initializeConsts / releaseConsts functions to the beginning/end of your program

Comment: Thanks andy - I'm using the above code in my add and I'm getting the compile error in my Switch statements:

"MyIntegerConstant" does not equate to an integer