# Is there an issue to use int for class property?

Tags: objective-c, class

When I started with Cocoa, I remember that I read somewhere that int/float and similar should not be used for class properties and to use NS* equivalents (like NSInteger).

Is there a real hidden issue here why would that be better or it was just a voluntary coding rule by a person where I read that (and I can't for the life of me find where was that)?

So, what is better:

```
@interface xx... 
    int myProp;
@end
```

or

```
@interface xx... 
    NSInteger *myProp;
@end
```

Comment: Good question Aleksandar. This earlier StackOverflow question/answer might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725/in-cocoa-do-you-prefer-nsinteger-or-just-regular-int-and-why

Comment: Just to make Chuck's point below explicit: the NSInteger version of your int example is "NSInteger myProp", *not* "NSInteger *myProp".

Comment: Ouch, thank smorgan. I kind of got into the habit of adding * after anything starting with NS O:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The int version is fine, but NSInteger is preferred. NSInteger isn't an object and doesn't have to be referenced with a pointer — it's just a typedef that will allow the variable to be the native word size on both 32-bit and 64-bit computers. So the best option would be:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject {
    NSInteger aNumber;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (id)init {
    [super init];
    number = 42;
}
@end
```

Comment: So it's basically a safe guard against pushing through the int size? Then there's nothing wrong to using int, if I'm certain it will be small maximum number (like 1000).

Comment: It's not a safeguard against anything. It just helps make your app architecture-independent. There is generally no good reason to use int over NSInteger — you don't gain anything. If you want to specify a small number and therefore conserve space, you should use a small type such as uint_16 or uint_8.

Answer (score 0):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725/in-cocoa-do-you-prefer-nsinteger-or-just-regular-int-and-why). NSInteger is architecture safe and is recommended from 10.5 onwards.