# Problem in Multiple button onclick event in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have created five buttons in a for loop dynamically. Now I want to associate an OnClick event with every button which do different actions. How I can do this and how can I detect which button is clicked?

```
for (NSUInteger i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    UIButton *myButton1 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] 
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 57,15, 15)];
    [myButton1 setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked1:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could asseble the selector name into a string and turn the string into a selector:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    NSString *actionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"buttonClicked%i", i];
    SEL action = NSSelectorFromString(actionName);
    // …
}
```

But as the buttons will probably do something similar, it would be better if they all called the same method, where you would simply tell the buttons apart by the `tag`:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    // …
    [button setTag:i];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void) buttonClicked: (id) button
{
    const int tag = [button tag];
    switch (tag) { /* … */ }
}
```

By the way, why do so many people insist on writing `NSInteger` when you can simply type `int`? Is there a difference? No that I know of.

Comment: FWIW: "When building 32-bit applications, NSInteger is a 32-bit integer. A 64-bit application treats NSInteger as a 64-bit integer." http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-DontLinkElementID_8

Comment: A-ha, there’s even a SO thread about them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating 5 buttons in a for loop?
Is there any particular reason why you're not using Interface Builder?

Also, the code you posted will place each button at the same position. A button will be on top of the previous button, and so on.