# CG/NSPoint-like integer tuple type?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Is there an appropriate structure provided in the Apple foundation kits to represent discrete coordinate systems?  I know I can just use the integral component of NSPoint and by convention keep it discrete, or even define my own.

However if there is one already which is typed correctly I would prefer that and avoid implicit / explicit type nastiness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of one that serves your exact needs. You could certainly use `CGPoint` or `NSPoint`, but since you know the values will be discrete integers, why waste the precision on a non-existent fractional part? In addition, repeated casts to integer values would get old quickly. You'd be much better served to create your own typedef using integer types, like so:

```
typedef struct _DiscretePoint {
    NSInteger x;
    NSInteger y;
} DiscretePoint;
```

You could also use `int32_t` instead of `NSInteger` if you know the values will never exceed the 32-bit range — this will conserve some space in 64-bit mode. (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725/in-cocoa-do-you-prefer-nsinteger-or-just-regular-int-and-why) for details about `NSInteger`, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I agree, there is really no appropriate structure that comes with the standard API's - I looked through places where it would make sense (such as raster image/device dimension methods, etc) and found they generally just used points or dual width/height parameters or accessors, or just use CGSize/CGPoint and floats everywhere.