# Is it wrong to use int in Cocoa and CocoaTouch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

What is the advantage of using something like `NSInteger` instead of `int` in code? I see this in examples a lot, including Apple's official code samples.

Comment: There's an interesting discussion on this subject here http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUInteger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a similar question here on SO.com: [In Cocoa do you prefer NSInteger or int, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725)  I prefer using `NSInteger` because it's future-proof, Apple now uses it over `int`, and it's the recommended way of doing things.

But it's not "wrong" to use `int`.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` were invented to solve 64-bit quantization issues on Mac OS (they are guaranteed to be the right size, no matter what architecture you are building for). I don't think it matters what you use on the iPhone, though I would get in the habit of using Apple's `NS`-types.

Anyway, if you ever port your code to Mac OS, it will be easier.

Comment: Isn't "int" supposed to be the right size anyway? Unless "right" means something different based on context, e.g. right size for the processor vs. right size for the libraries.

Comment: Mac OS X, along with most versions of Unix, uses LP64. In LP64, longs, and pointers are 64 bits, and ints are 32 bits.

http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html

Answer (score 2):

- In 32-bit code (including the iPhone): `int` is 4 bytes, `long` is 4 bytes, pointers are 4 bytes
- In 64-bit code: `int` is 4 bytes, `long` is 8 bytes, pointers are 8 bytes

Many existing APIs (incorrectly, for historical reasons) used `int` in 32-bit mode but must use `long` in 64-bit mode.

In C, `int` and `long` are not equivalent types, so if you use `int` you may be incompatible with the 64-bit API, and if you use `long` you may be incompatible with the 32-bit API.  By using `NSInteger` your code will be compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of these APIs.

So if you're using an API that specifies NSInteger, then you should use NSInteger.

In your own code and your own APIs:

- If you need a 4-byte integer, use `int`
- If you need a pointer-sized integer, use `long` or `NSInteger`
- if you need an 8-byte integer, use `long long`

The reason you wouldn't necessarily use NSInteger for everything is that 8-byte integers are overkill for many purposes.

Comment: I’d say, if you need a 4-byte integer, use `int32_t` (and, of course, `int64_t` for 8-byte). This way you express clearly the size and don’t depend on the platform/architecture.