# using NSInteger in a loop

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsinteger

Do a NSInteger occupies memory? Should we use it in a FOR loop?

Comment: Also note that if you have a loop with an integer inside, the integer's scope is the loop. Upon next loop, a new integer will be used and the old one gets out of scope. So no matter how often you loop, you occupy 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Apple documentation, a NSInteger is this :

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

It's just 4 bytes on an iPhone, just like an int, you don't have to worry about memory.

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger is just an alias for the native integer type.  Cmd+Dbl Click on it and see.

1) It uses stack memory (I assume) while it is in scope and releases it when it goes out of scope.

2) Yes, use it in a for loop.

Also, see [In Cocoa do you prefer NSInteger or int, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725/in-cocoa-do-you-prefer-nsinteger-or-just-regular-int-and-why)